# I need to find a smallest section of a string that contains all of the characters I'm searching for

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
$string = 'JFICCDKENJTKDIC';
```

and I want to find the smallest window that contains the letters T,C,&D (TKDIC in this example).

I see that there is a similar question to this, but it is not using php.

Comment: OK, and have you tried something?

Comment: TKDIC as example is not sufficient to formulate a regular expression. Must every letter exist? Must every letter exists only once? How many letters are allowed between the letters T, C & D? What are the exact rules that should the regex meet?